Providing user object throughout Flutter app using go_router package?
I have a flutter app wherein user can come to home screen via 3 ways: signup, signin or user is already signedin (config bloc). When any of the flow returns a success state (have used bloc for that) i store the value of user in a User object. And then I route to home page which is 0th tab from amongst 4 tabs. I am using go_router package for navigation like so:
 StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
          return MainWrapper(navigationShell: navigationShell);
        },
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
          /// Branch Home
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorHome,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                  path: "/home",
                  name: "home",
                  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return HomeScreen();
                  }),
            ],
          ),
          // / Branch Notifications
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorBookings,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                  path: "/bookings",
                  name: "bookings",
                  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return BookingsScreen();
                  }),
            ],
          ),
          // / Branch favourites
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorFavourites,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                  path: "/favourites",
                  name: "favourites",
                  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return FavouritesScreen();
                  }),
            ],
          ),

          /// Branch Profile
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorProfile,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                  path: "/profile",
                  name: "profile",
                  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return ProfileScreen();
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),

Let's say I want to provide user object to all these screens, can I achieve it? I know how to do it to a single route like so:
GoRoute(
        path: AppRoutes.otpVerify,
        name: AppRoutes.otpVerify,
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
          final extras = state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>?;
          final contact = extras?[AppConstants.contact] as String;
          final flowType = extras?[AppConstants.flowType] as FlowType;
          final user = extras?[AppConstants.user] as User?;
          final userID = extras?[AppConstants.userId] as String?;
          return CustomTransitionPage<void>(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => OtpBloc(
                  otpRepository: OtpRepository(otpVerification: OTPImp())),
              child: OtpVerficationScreen(
                user: user,
                contact: contact,
                type: flowType,
                userID: userID,
              ),
            ),
            transitionsBuilder: (
              context,
              animation,
              secondaryAnimation,
              child,
            ) =>
                FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child),
          );
        },
      ),

and adding info as extra
context.push(AppRoutes.otpVerify,
                                              extra: {
                                                AppConstants.contact:
                                                    _emailPhoneController.text,
                                                AppConstants.flowType:
                                                    FlowType.forgotPassword,
                                                AppConstants.userId:
                                                    value.message.userID
                                              });

But how do I provide user to my Main Wrapper? The signin bloc is as follows:
class SignInBloc extends Bloc<SignInEvent, SignInState> {
  SignInRepository signInRepository;
  User? user;
  SignInBloc({required this.signInRepository}) : super(const _Initial()) {
    on<_ClickedSignInButton>(_onClickedSignInButton);
  }

  void _onClickedSignInButton(event, emit) async {
    emit(const SignInState.signingIn());
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    try {
      final response = await signInRepository.signUpUser(event.data);
      user = response;
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setString(AppConstants.user, jsonEncode(response!.toJson()));
      emit(SignInState.success(
          msg: "Welcome ${response.firstname}", user: response));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(SignInState.failure(error: e.toString()));
    }
  }
}


Config (user already signed in) bloc and signup bloc are similar to it.
The success states are
user = response;
  emit(ConfigState.success(user: user!));

and
user = response;
emit(SignupState.success(
         msg: "Welcome ${response.firstname}", user: response));

In all 3 flows, user goes to home page tab, how do I inject object to MainWrapper so that it's accessible throughout the app?
